# Switching a stereo audio signal without distortion

Tags: microcontroller, audio, opto-isolator

I need to switch a stereo signal in a lossless, non-distorted manner. Simply put, I need to control ON/OFF for each channel. Should I use MOSFETs or optocouplers? I believe the signal ranges from -2.5V to 2.5V ... standard 3.5mm output. Cluebats at the ready :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the above.

Ideally use CMOS analogue switches like 405x series (+/-5v analogue supply and switching voltage range, logic 0/5v compatible).

Comment: Sounds like the best option. Please recommend a specific part number.

Answer (score 2):

Relays are popular for audio applications, and are useful for switching either line-level signals (e.g. from an mp3 player) or speaker-level.  If you're only switching line-level you can use analog switches, such as TI's [TS5A2066](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ts5a2066.pdf).  If you need to control each channel separately, a dual SPST type would probably be best.

EDIT: Apologies -- I missed the +/-2.5V signal requirement.  I'll defer you to Neil_UK's post.

Comment: This looks mechanical - is that correct?

Comment: Relays are electromechanical -- supplying current to a relay coil opens or closes a mechanical contact.  Thus you can have an electrically-controlled ON/OFF switch.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that it may be more prudent to turn off the audio signal by shunting or shorting it to ground. That way there is no non-linear device (like any semiconductor) in the THRU-path of the audio.

Consider also that hard metal contacts (like a relay) will have vanishingly low distortion compared to any semiconductor device.  Suitable relays are readily available in DIP packages same size as an IC.  Even latching relays which require no holding power.

Answer (score 0):

Telcom-grade relays in DIP package are ideal for this application.

Note that the relay-contact material and plating will greatly affect the reliability of your system.  One of the reasons that I mention telcom-grade relays is that these are designed both for reliability and vanishingly-low resistance values with very low values of current.

Relays that are NOT designed for audio or instrumentation purposes will have contacts that can develop contact resistance when passing tiny currents.  The problem shows up as distortion or even loss of signal until the relay is exercised.

There is a spec in the datasheet that is often called "wetting current".  This is the minimum current required through the contact to keep it clean and conductive.

Telcom relays with gold-plated bifurcated contacts are the most-reliable readily-available relays available.

In years gone by, I would have suggested that Mercury-Wetted relays would be a good choice.  Unfortunately, these are no longer readily available.

Comment: Are optocouplers and MOSFETs completely out of the question? If yes, can you recommend some parts for this? Also, do you agree with @calcium3000 in his recommendation for the TS5A2066?